# MariaDB: missing some columns when exporting query results to a csv file

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this query that correctly displays the data I need:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, d.dob, d.address, d.hourly_rate,
       d.designation,d.department_id    
  FROM employee_details e    
  JOIN users u 
    ON d.employee_id = u.user_id;
```

But when I export the results to `CSV` file, I can't see the columns names: (`users.first_name` and `users.last_name`)

Comment: can you show the method used to export the data to csv by editing the question.

Comment: it works now... i just have to customize the export..thanks for the answer though

Comment: Voting to close because the problem and the solution remain a mystery.  So, why clutter this site.